# AdMob SDK for windows 8

Tags: windows-8, admob

[Google's AdMob page(Monetize your app)](http://www.google.com/ads/admob/monetize.html?_adc=ww-en-et-developers_mobile) says the following:

> 1. Cross platform
>
> AdMob connects you with millions of advertisers looking to reach users across platforms, including Android, iOS and **Windows 8**.

I have searched extensively, but failed to find the SDK for Windows 8.

Could anyone provide a pointer?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/download#downloadwp

Comment: I am looking for the SDK for Windows 8, not Windows Phone 8.

Comment: Ah. Windows 8 is not supported. Looks like a typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Android SDK is at 
https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/download#downloadplay

There is no SDK specific to Windows8. SDK is dependent upon target dev platform, iOS, Android, WindowsPhone8 etc. That same page provides the SDKs for all platforms.

Comment: So, do you think "Windows 8" is a typo and they meant "Windows Phone 8"?

Comment: Yes. Definitely a typo on the page.