# Windows phone 7 & 8 AdMob

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, admob, inmobi

Have anyone used InMobi SDK for Windows Phone app for both Windows 7 and Windows 8 AdMob ? If yes what is the procedure?

I already tried this following code

```
<InMobiSDK:IMAdView 
                  Name="AdView1"
                        DisplayText="Test Ad"
                        AdSize="15"
                        RefreshInterval="20"
                        AnimationType="FLIP_FROM_LEFT"
                        AdTextColor="#131212"
                        AdBackgroundColor="#E40707"
                        AppId="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" 
                        Background="#73808080" 
                        Foreground="Black"
                        Height="50"
                        Width="320"
                        AdRequestFailed="AdView1_AdRequestFailed"
                        AdRequestLoaded="AdView1_AdRequestLoaded"
                        DismissFullAdScreen="AdView1_DismissFullAdScreen"
                        LeaveApplication="AdView1_LeaveApplication"
                        ShowFullAdScreen="AdView1_ShowFullAdScreen">
                      <!-- Set IMAdRquest Properties-->
            <InMobiSDK:IMAdView.IMAdRequest>
                <InMobiSDK:IMAdRequest IsInTestMode="True"  >
                    <InMobiSDK:IMAdRequest.UserInfo >
                        <InMobiSDK:UserInfo 
                            Age="20"
                            AreaCode="110"
                            Education="MastersDegree"
                            Ethnicity="Asian"
                            Gender="Male"
                            Income="10000"
                            PostalCode="11001"
                            >
                        </InMobiSDK:UserInfo>
                    </InMobiSDK:IMAdRequest.UserInfo>
                </InMobiSDK:IMAdRequest>
            </InMobiSDK:IMAdView.IMAdRequest>
        </InMobiSDK:IMAdView>
```

Please Help me for the same..

Answer (score 1):

Here is the InMobi Windows [integration guide](https://www.inmobi.com/support/article/?id=24114182?id=24114182):

and Admob supports Windows Phone 8 and NOT Windows 8. Read this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20155919/admob-sdk-for-windows-8) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

As per the provided code snippet, its the older SDK version with "IsInTestMode" property which will not display test ads anymore. However to receive test ads with the newer SDK, the test device should be registered with inmobi using diagnostics flow.

To get test ads:

1. Download the new SDK bundle from [here](https://dl.inmobi.com/SDK/InMobi_windows_SDK.zip)
2. Follow the complete Windows SDK integration guidelines provided [here](https://www.inmobi.com/support/article/?id=24114182?id=24114182#sthash.rZozuVUO.dpbs)
3. Follow steps provided [here](https://www.inmobi.com/support/integration/23925038/22188957/windows-phone-8-sdk-integration-guide/#findtestdev) to register you device with inmobi

Comment: Can u please help me in doing fullscreen add?